# sed anchor characters in [^]

Tags: sed

Why does sed, if we use the negation expression`[^ ]` treat anchor characters like `\b` or `\B` as real characters? E. g. one would expect the following expressions to yield the same result, but they don't:

```
$ echo 'apple pear melon banana cherry papaya' | sed 's/[^\b]a[^\b]/u/g'
apple pu melon baua cherry uaya
$ echo 'apple pear melon banana cherry papaya' | sed 's/\Ba\B/u/g'
apple peur melon bununa cherry pupuya
```

If there was no `\B`, how could we negate `\b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of `\b` or `\B` is a character.  Both are zero-width patterns that matches *between* characters.

The `\b` pattern matches at a word boundary, i.e. between a character that is a "word character" and a character that is not a "word character".

The `\B` pattern matches at a non-word boundary, i.e. between a two characters that are both either "word characters" or not.

The pattern `[^\b]` matches *one character*. This is why `pear` is transformed into `pu`, you replace `ear` (the `a` and the surrounding characters).

With GNU `sed`, `[^\b]` matches a character that is not an `\` or a `b`.

There is no way to use a character class to replace the use of `\B` that I'm aware of.

The `\b` and `\B` patterns are supported by GNU `sed`. Both GNU `sed` and BSD `sed` also has `\<` and `\>` for explicitly matching at the start and end of a word, and BSD `sed` additionally supports the POSIX patterns `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` (but GNU `sed` does not).  The POSIX patterns can't be negated (`[^[:>:]]` does not work).

To get a *similar* effect without using `\B`, you could use something like

```
$ echo 'apple pear melon banana cherry papaya' | sed 's/\([[:alnum:]]\)a\([[:alnum:]]\)/\1u\2/g'
apple peur melon bunana cherry pupaya
```

That is, match an alphanumeric character on either side of the `a`, and then include these two flanking characters in the replacement.  Note that since the replacement only happens for non-overlapping matches, this would not properly substitute the `a`'s in a string containing multiple consecutive `a`'s (or `a`'s in every second position).  See how `banana` that does not come out as `bununa` due to this.

To sort that out, you could introduce a loop in the `sed` program:

```
sed -e :top -e 's/\([[:alnum:]]\)a\([[:alnum:]]\)/\1u\2/g' -e ttop
```

This performs the replacement over the input line as many times as needed until all overlapping pattern matches have been handled.

Comment: Note that POSIX doesn't specify `[[:<:]]`. While it's shaped like a POSIX character class, it's not a character class at all.

Comment: For ast-open's `sed`, `\b` means a backspace character (like in many other utilities including `echo`, `printf` and `awk` and `$'...'`).

Comment: The section about _The additional
      word delimiters `\<` and `\>` are provided   to ease compatibility with
      traditional SVR4 systems but are not portable and should be avoided_ in the re_format man page of OpenBSD makes little sense. `\<` is more portable than `[[:<:]]` and comes from `vi` (so from BSD) long before SVR4. AFAIK, `\b` comes from `perl`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. I might submit a bug report/patch to the OpenBSD lists when I find the time. It's been on my mind.

Comment: `[^\b]` matches a _collating element_ , so could match more than one character. `printf '%s\n' 'a\bdz' | LC_ALL=hu_HU.UTF-8 sed 's/[^\b]/<&>/g'` outputs `<a>\b<dz>` with GNU `sed` for instance.

Comment: Note that for `\<`/`\b`... a _word_ character includes `_`, it's `[[:alnum:]_]`